# Migrate Applications with ADFS Activity Report to actual application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adfs

Using the ADFS activity report to migrate our applications to AAD. Everything shows as Ready.
But how do you import the ADFS configuration into a new enterprise application?
Or do you need to create everything from scratch?

You can find the image below for your reference, it shows the ‘Dropbox’ application as ready for migration from ADFS to Azure AD: -
[Dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBfkW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   You don’t need to import ADFS configuration into a new Enterprise application for ‘Dropbox’ as its application federation configuration is already imported and made available for Azure AD users for smooth SSO authentication purposes in Enterprise application gallery. The image as posted by you regarding Dropbox application import into Azure from ADFS confirms that Dropbox is available for migration in Azure AD and its relative setup is a matter of few clicks and configurations.

•   Also, the message in the image posted by you is only displayed for those applications that are readily available in Azure AD Enterprise applications and not legacy applications (applications that are not SaaS apps and need to be setup manually in Azure AD enterprise applications as a non-gallery app). When ADFS Health Connect communicates with Azure AD and syncs the relying party trust information from ADFS on-premises server, Azure AD compares it with the ready, available and Integrated SaaS applications in its gallery to be provisioned in the respective Azure AD tenant through the ‘create’ option. Similarly, when you do this provision/create ‘Dropbox’ SaaS application from Enterprise application gallery, it detects automatically through the ADFS Health Connect activity report that ‘Dropbox’ is configured as a federated RPT in the synced on-premises ADFS server and asks the user to migrate it to Azure AD.

For more detailed information on migrating Dropbox application from ADFS to Azure AD, please refer to the link below which discusses setting up of SSO authentication through SAML in Azure AD.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OThlTA239lU